# springboot mysql Connection security

Tags: java, spring, mysql-connector

I used Springboot to build a Java web project, and the MySQL database connection username and password were configured in the application.yml file, but this is not secure enough. Is there any other secure way to configure user passwords for MySQL databases?

I hope to obtain a secure way to configure MySQL database user passwords, which cannot use plaintext in the code

Comment: I have both MySQL database environments for Windows Server 2019 and Centos 7.9. Windows credentials can be used in the Windows environment, but I don't know how to configure them specifically

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can leverage Jasypt library which provides a convenient mechanism for encrypting properties.
Here's an example of how to configure Jasypt with Spring Boot:

1.Add the Jasypt dependency to your project's pom.xml (Maven):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
<artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

2.Configure the encryption password in your application.yml:

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
   password: your_encryption_password # This should be kept secret elsewhere
```

3.Encrypt your MySQL database password using Jasypt CLI tool or any other means supported by Jasypt. For example, if your original password is plaintextPassword, after encryption, it might look something like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_db
    username: your_user
    password: ENC(encryptedPassword) # Replace 'encryptedPassword' with the actual encrypted value
```

4.Now, when Spring Boot starts, Jasypt will automatically decrypt the encrypted properties.

Comment: year, I am using jasypt 2.1.2 to match JDK 1.8, which works normally